# Xaxis date labels not formating plotly pyhton

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I am trying to shorten size of the xaxis labels on my graph. I would like to only have hour and minute. At the moment my .csv file holds it in the full format '23/09/2022  00:10:00', etc
Tried to applied some formatting found in google but it does not seem to update my graph.
Anyone could advise on this please?

```
df = two_days_data.sort_values(by='Date')
mask = df["TTT"] == station

fig = px.line(df[mask], x='Date', y="AAA", title='BBB.', markers=True)
fig.update_xaxes(type='category', tickformat="%H %M")

return fig
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you will need to do... first - make sure the df.Date column is in datetime format. You can do this by using `pd.to_datatime()`

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) ## Add format if you get an error to specify non-standard format, if present
```

Then use the tickformat as below.

```
fig.update_xaxes(tickformat="%H:%M")
```

This should give you the plot with the x-axis labels in HH:MM format

**My full data**

```
    Date    name    AAA
0   2022-09-21 15:10:00 Some name 1 224
1   2022-09-21 15:10:00 Some name 2 239
2   2022-09-21 15:10:00 Some name 3 254
3   2022-09-21 15:10:00 Some name 4 269
4   2022-09-21 15:10:00 Some name 5 284
5   2022-09-21 15:10:00 Some name 6 299
6   2022-09-21 15:10:00 Some name 7 314
7   2022-09-21 15:10:00 Some name 8 329
8   2022-09-21 16:10:00 Some name 1 230
9   2022-09-21 16:10:00 Some name 2 239
10  2022-09-21 16:10:00 Some name 3 248
11  2022-09-21 16:10:00 Some name 4 257
12  2022-09-21 16:10:00 Some name 5 266
13  2022-09-21 16:10:00 Some name 6 275
14  2022-09-21 16:10:00 Some name 7 284
15  2022-09-21 16:10:00 Some name 8 293
16  2022-09-21 17:10:00 Some name 1 200
17  2022-09-21 17:10:00 Some name 2 213
18  2022-09-21 17:10:00 Some name 3 226
19  2022-09-21 17:10:00 Some name 4 239
20  2022-09-21 17:10:00 Some name 5 252
21  2022-09-21 17:10:00 Some name 6 265
22  2022-09-21 17:10:00 Some name 7 278
23  2022-09-21 17:10:00 Some name 8 291
24  2022-09-21 18:10:00 Some name 1 304
25  2022-09-21 18:10:00 Some name 2 317
26  2022-09-21 18:10:00 Some name 3 330
27  2022-09-21 18:10:00 Some name 4 343
28  2022-09-21 18:10:00 Some name 5 356
29  2022-09-21 18:10:00 Some name 6 369
30  2022-09-21 18:10:00 Some name 7 382
31  2022-09-21 18:10:00 Some name 8 395
32  2022-09-21 19:10:00 Some name 1 408
33  2022-09-21 19:10:00 Some name 2 421
34  2022-09-21 19:10:00 Some name 3 434
35  2022-09-21 19:10:00 Some name 4 447
36  2022-09-21 19:10:00 Some name 5 460
37  2022-09-21 19:10:00 Some name 6 473
38  2022-09-21 19:10:00 Some name 7 486
39  2022-09-21 19:10:00 Some name 8 499
```

**Code**

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
mask = df["name"] == "Some name 1"

fig = px.line(df[mask], x='Date', y="AAA", title='BBB.', markers=True)
fig.update_xaxes(tickformat="%H %M")
```

**Plot**

[image]

Comment: I have applied your suggestion and see some light in the tunnel.
However, despite 'T' in between date and time which suggests me it in the right format,

fig.update_xaxes(tickformat="%H:%M") does not do anything..

Comment: datetime64[ns](1) after applying df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
and still not updating. 21/09/2022  15:10:00 this is the format

Comment: I have added first few rows from the dataset. It contains 1 row per 'name' per hour and 609 rows ('names') in total per hour. Every hour another 609 rows is being added with the next hour at date column. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes correct. There is a dropdown working correctly above the graph where you can select desired 'name' and it shows last 48h data on the graph. The only missing part is the time which I have in the form I do not like much.

Comment: Ok, figured out your problem. You need to change `fig.update_xaxes(type='category', tickformat="%H %M")` to `fig.update_xaxes(tickformat="%H %M")`. I am updating the full answer in a minute. You are saying that it should be hour and minutes, in which case you should not set type to Category, which will make it as a string

Comment: Thank you for your continues support. Unfortunately 'category' is important for me as I want every tick to be displayed on the xaxis label if this is something achievable.

Comment: While plotting, the axis info needs to be in datetime format, else plotly wont understand or adjust the distances. As shown in the plot, it shouldn't matter to you if it is categorical or datetime. If you need it for something else, you can convert it back to string and then use it. For the axis, I would recommend this as it will work whether you have one entry in a day or 10

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%d.%m - %H:%M')


fig.update_xaxes(type='category', tickangle=45)
```

This has given me what I wanted.

Thank you!